# Imageshack API almost working

Tags: php, redirect, asp-classic, imageshack

This tutorial http://www.blocsoft.com/blog/imageshack.asp shows a great way to upload to imageshack and get a image url back although its for ASP and I need it in PHP.

Any ideas if and how this could be done?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Does none of the tools shown when Googling `imageshack API PHP` work for you? Some of them look quite promising.

Comment: They do look promising but none do exactly what I need (unlike the asp one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rewrote the asp to php, no clue if it works haven't tested it, but if the asp does work then the php should also.

index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AJAX image upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://imageshack.us/redirect_api.php" target="AXframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="media"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY">
      <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="http://example.com/error.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://example.com/success.php?one=%y&two=%u&three=%s&four=%b&five=%i">
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <iframe style="visibility:hidden" id="AXframe" name="AXframe"></iframe>
    <div id="link"></div>
    <div id="yfrog"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

success.php

```
<?php
  $str1 = $_GET["one"];
  $str2 = $_GET["two"];
  $str3 = $_GET["three"];
  $str4 = $_GET["four"];
  $str5 = $_GET["five"];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  parent.document.getElementById('yfrog').innerHTML =  '<?php echo($str1); ?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = '<?php echo($str2); ?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = '<img src="http://img<?php echo($str3); ?>.imageshack.us/img<?php echo($str3); ?>/<?php echo($str4); ?>/<?php echo($str5); ?>">';
</script>
```

error.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("There was an error uploading the file.");
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't seem to work. I get a broken image icon and no links, and the image icon points to an empty spot at imageshack (http://img.imageshack.us/img//)

Comment: I got it working just by echoing the variables that are in success.php Thanks heaps!